# Get Min Date from a date range for a column value in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

There is below table with below columns, 2nd column is Date type:

```
Report ID     Due Date
100           4/2/2020
111           4/1/2020
121           3/20/2020
100           3/27/2020
121           3/31/2020
100           3/31/2020
100           4/14/2020
```

I want to get minimum date for a particular report id column. Eg for Report ID=100, min due date is 3/27/2020. I tried to apply below formula in a column which is not giving a correct value.

```
{=MIN(IF($A$674:$A$690=100, $B$674:$B$690))}
```

I should get 3/27/2020 but it gives me output as 1/0/1900.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved now, there was no error in formula but the first column was showing error in column and I converted it to number. The output is coming correct now. Thanks